# How to access the content of a webpage displayed in a tab from a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In a Firefox extension, I am attempting to add a form into the web page by inserting DOM elements, and then process any data that the user enters in the form.

I have tried several methods, but have been unable to get my form inserted into the webpage's `document`. I tried using the different types of add-ons, Overlay (XUL) and the Add-on SDK, but I have not been able to get it to work.

1. Overlay/XUL: I investigated and found nothing that specifically showed me how to change the contents of a web page.
2. Using the Addons SDK:  The only working code which I found was the demo code in "[Modifying Web Pages Based on URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL)" which appeared to give: 
   `var html = sth;`
   `$("body").html(html);`
   I tried: 
   `$('.id_of_ele').html('I want to show');`
   It doesn't work.
3. So far the only thing which has gotten me close is to use `unsafeWindow.document`, but I believe that is a really a bad idea, and the code looks really bad.

How do I access the the `document` of a webpage from a Firefox extension?

Comment: This appears to be  more of a rant than a real question.

Comment: @MikeW, updated. thanks~

Comment: I understand your frustration. When I first started with addons it took me a couple months of my own exploring and finally i got it working. to help you get started see this topic though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933911/which-technology-should-i-use-to-build-add-ons-for-firefox/25934552?noredirect=1#comment40600289_25934552

Comment: oh wow they deleted the post i spent forever making.  that is absolutely ridiculous. thankfully i backed it up here though, so check it out: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/51b62b356b3a21010a4d

Comment: @Noitidart: I suggest the use of the [Textarea Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/) extension to save all the edited contents of textboxes.  It enables more extensive recovery from crashes, mistaken deletes, etc.

Comment: thanks man ill check it out. but stackoverflow moderators deleted this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for examples of known working code, you can always [download one or more extensions from Mozilla Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/) which do something close to what you want to accomplish and look at how they do it. Obviously, you should look at the license (linked on each extensions page) to see what the legal status of the code it. There are literally thousands of working examples there.  The vast majority of which have code which is licensed in a way which permits you to re-use it.

The jQuery accesses which you are trying to use rely on the `document` variable pointing to the document which you are wanting to modify. In the context in which you are running, a Firefox add-on, the `document` variable may, by default, point to a document which is an ancestor of the webpage you are interested in or not be defined at all.  What `document` actually is will depend on the context from which your add-on code was invoked. In a Firefox add-on, the `document` variable will almost never, by default, point to the content of a web page. You have to remember that you are writing code that is intended to run in a context that is *much* larger (entire browser/user agent) than that which is used for content scripts on a webpage (context within the browser is restricted to only the content of the webpage from which the script was run, or data which is obtained from references originating from within the page).

**Gaining access to the document for the currently selected tab:**

Changing the content document is very easy.  You can change it just like you would from any JavaScript. The issue that you may find frustrating is obtaining a reference to the document.

Firefox [overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) and [restartless/bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) have a great amount of power over the entire browser. However, the context, and what `window` points to, or even if it is defined, depends greatly on how the JavaScript was invoked. This can be both confusing and frustrating. On MDN, there is a document "[Working with windows in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code)" which describes many of the issues.

From extensions you have access to all windows and tabs. However, what you probably want is just some code that works to get you access to the current selected document.

This should work from all contexts to get you a reference to the document for the currently selected tab:

```
var selectedTabWindow = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                       .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                       .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
var selectedTabDocument = selectedTabWindow.content.document;
```

If you have code which you are converting from a content script which just expects to find `window` and `document` objects, you could write something like:

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    var window;
} else {
    //Keep a reference to whatever was defined as window.
    var originalWindow = window;
}
//Get the window from the most recently selected tab.
window = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                       .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                       .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

//Now that we have a window for the most recently selected tab,
//  get the document for it.
if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    var document;
} else {
    //Keep a reference to whatever was defined as document.
    var originalDocument = document;
}
document = window.content.document;

//Now that we have a window for the most recently selected tab,
//  get the gBrowser for it.
if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
    var gBrowser;
} else {
    //Keep a reference to whatever was defined as gBrowser.
    var originalGBrowser = gBrowser;
}
gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
```

The above will, obviously, overwrite any currently variables currently defined as `window`, `document` and `gBrowser`. Depending on the context in which you are running, and the scope in which you define these this could be either a good thing, or it might be a bad idea to change that reference.  For example, if the code is running in a popup window then `window` is a reference to window of the popup. In that case, you can get a reference to the window from which the popup was opened with:

```
var windowWhichOpendedThisOne = window.opener;
var documentForWindowWhichOpendedThisOne = window.opener.content.document;
```

If you are in an event handler, then you can get the window for the target of the event from:

```
var windowInWhichEventTargetExists = event.view;
```

**Choosing what to do based on the URL:**

Once you have the correct `document` it should be quite easy to choose what to do based on the document's URL:

```
var currentUrl = document.location.href;
```

Comment: e10 is coming around so accessing stuff will be tricky maybe we should just recommend to him to use addon sdk

Comment: @Noitidart: I had marked this page as one I may need to update at a later time. However, e10 is still in development, is unstable and is not enabled by default (I've tried enabling it in my primary profile, which I am running on Aurora). With e10 enabled, it effectively just locks up. There are supposed to be shims in place to make extensions work for a considerable time. If they remove those shims, they are going to break any non-SDK add-on that accesses document content. That would be a Bad Idea™; not that Mozilla has never executed a Bad Idea™ with respect to extensions.